# Simple Substring Issue

Tags: java, string, methods, substring

My teacher wants us to make a letter 'o' move around the console.  The letter 'o' has been coded to appear in the center of the console screen.  I have already created the movingRight and movingDown methods but I'm having difficulty creating the movingLeft and movingUp methods.  Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

static String letter = "\n\n\n\n                                                                               O";
String whenmovingup = letter.substring(0, 1);
char whenmovingleft = letter.charAt(letter.length() - 2);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print(letter);
    input.nextLine();

    if (input.equals("left")) {
        movingLeft();
    }
    if (input.equals("right")) {
        movingRight();
    }
    if (input.equals("up")) {
        movingUp();
    }
    if (input.equals("down")) {
        movingDown();
    }

}

    public static void movingRight(){
        letter = " " + letter;
    }
    public static void movingDown(){
        letter = "\n" + letter;
    }
    public static void movingLeft(){
        letter.remove(whenmovingleft);
    }
    public static void movingUp(){
        letter.remove(whenmovingup);
    }
}
```

I'm having an issue with removing the whenmovingfeft and whenmovingup substrings from my original string letter.  It's giving an error ('The method remove(char) is undefined for the type String'), and I'm not sure what needs to be done.

Does anyone know how this can be resolved?
Thanks in advance for all responses.

Comment: *"It's giving me errors"* - what errors, exactly, are you getting? Please edit the error messages into your question.

Comment: Thanks for your help Greg.  The pop-up tells me that this is an invalid way of using a String type.

Comment: 'The method remove(char) is undefined for the type String'

Comment: There's no `remove` method for `String`s.  If you want to delete one character from a `String`, and you know the position of the character you wnat to delete, you basically need to use `substring`, either once or twice.

Comment: There's now a new error. 'Type mismatch: cannot convert from char to String'

Comment: You haven't changed your code (or added any new code) in your question, so we don't know what could be causing the new error.  Please see the javadoc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) for the correct usage of `String` methods.  If a method needs a `String`  parameter, a `char` won't work.

Comment: `Character.toString(c)` will convert a `char` to a `String` whose length is 1.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `remove` method for a string. However, there is a `replace` method that may do what you want. Note that it does not modify the string object, but it *returns* a new string. So you would do:

```
letter = letter.replace(whenmovingup, "");
```

Note that there are two slightly different overloads of `replace` which do different things depending on whether you ask it to remove a `String` or `char`. The `replace(String, String)` method replaces *one* occurrence, while the `replace(char, char)` replaces *all* occurrences. You want just one, so declare `whenmovingleft` as a `String` and initialise it appropriately.

Comment: Whenever I try and change the whenmovingup declaration to a string, I get this error message: 'Type mismatch: cannot convert from char to String'

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned you'll have to initialise it appropriately, with a `String` instead of a `char`. You successfully initialise `whenmovingup` with a `String`, so do something similar for `whenmovingleft`.

Comment: Is there a .stringat function? However else I rewrite this declaration gives me the same error as before.

Comment: Just as in the line above, use `letter.substring(...)`, which returns a `String`.